# DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie persist after server reboot

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I am using mvc 5 with external log in with facebook, but after every server reboot, the user would be logged out of the system. That defeats the purpose of oAuth? I can't find any properties to make them persist through reboots

this is how the startup.auth looks like..

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/External"),
    ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0),
    SlidingExpiration = true
});

app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `web.config` file uses the default auto-generated settings, the server's encryption keys will change each time the web server restarts. To fix this the `machineKey` element needs to have fixed key values.

An online `machineKey` generator: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Comment: Does it pose any security concern?

Comment: No (but the `machineKey` attributes should always use the most secure algorithm values supported by your version of IIS). This is the mechanism used in a web farm to ensure all the servers are using identical key sets.

Comment: it works now, thanks devstuff, so if the key ever gets compromise, we have to change it manually? And face an 'all-user-signed-out' issue?

Comment: Exactly. If you're part of a larger developer team you may wish to have separate Debug and Production settings, with Production only available to whoever is doing deployments. That will minimize any exposure window.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so the equivalent of remember me for password login is not an option in the default template, basically you can do this by changing the isPersistent to true inside of ExternalLoginCallback

```
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
```

Comment: i have set that as true, but it still doesn't "remember me"